# rails params[:user_id] return nil even they present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, parameters

When i submit the form and rails console shows parameter passing as

```
Processing by RfpsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OeKck54onJ6o72ABYvB6jMyBnU5X7BHY6NKH1sUtcHU=", "***rfp"=>{"user_id"=>"64***", "client_id"=>"3", "cms"=>"other2", "othercms"=>"dasda", "otherecommerce"=>"", "numberofpage"=>"", "designcomplexity"=>"", "browser"=>"","commit"=>"Create Rfp", "project_id"=>"18"}
```

in the controller when i check `if params[:user_id].present?` it always shows nil even though user_id is 64 as shown above 
plz help me why does it happen

**EDITS**

```
Started GET "/projects/18/rfps/157" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-23 10:16:24 +0530
Processing by RfpsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"18", "id"=>"157"}
  Current user: anonymous
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):



def show
 @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@rfp = Rfp.find(params[:id])
    # r  = Rfp.find(params[:user_id])

    # m  = Rfp.find(params[:user_id])

    if params[:rfp][:user_id].present?
        @coo = User.where(:id => params[:rfp][:user_id]).first

    end
 end
```

in view i am jst printing name

```
  Coordinator<%= @coo.firstname %>
```

Comment: Post your `RfpsController`

Comment: @Pavan which def exacly coz it is large

Comment: Of course it is `show` action.

Comment: I already seen man.I edited your post too.

Comment: Now where is this `@client_name = Client.where(:id => params[:client_id])` gone? you are totally messing it.

Comment: @Pavan I just put it in comment

Comment: you have changed your code now, what's wrong with you?

Comment: @RSB Now it just as shown in post

Comment: You are not getting user_id in your parameters

Comment: @RSB but in console it shows !How strange

Comment: Its showing this, where is user_id? `Parameters: {"project_id"=>"18", "id"=>"157"}`

Comment: @RSB client_name = Client.where(:id => @rfp.client_id).first solve the issue  thanks for pointing me !!but still not sure why  client_id not pass

Answer (score 4):

Do this, here `:user_id` is under `:rfp`

```
if params[:rfp][:user_id].present?
```

Comment: it shows `NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: Now you are getting error for some other problem not due to this, post your error log

Comment: You need to post your error log for that and also your controller code

Comment: well now you're rendering an entirely different controller with different params, so of course it won't work!

Comment: @sevenseacat got it right, previously you had problem in `create` action but now its in `show` action

Comment: I've edited my answer, in show action again you were accessing `user_id` by `params[:user_id]` which is wrong, use `params[:rfp][:user_id]`

Comment: Use `params[:rfp][:client_id]` in place of `params[:client_id]`

Comment: @RSB hard luck !!no result same way

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if params['***rfp'][:user_id].present?
    @coo = User.where(id: params['***rfp'][:user_id]).first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

because `params[:user_id]` is not present.

`params[:rfp][:user_id]` is 64, however.

Comment: plz see the comments below's ans

Answer (score 0):

You have your `user_id` in `rfp`,by doing just `params[:user_id]` is not sufficient to get the value here.so it returns **nil**.

you have to do

```
params[:rfp][:user_id] #=> 64
```

to get the value of `user_id`.

So now by doing `if params[:rfp]{:user_id].present? #=> true`

will return `true`

Comment: see the first answers' comment

Comment: @Anish Yeah! I have seen and responded with my comment under your question too.